# How to get a crisp shadow from object using a spot light?

Tags: shadows

I am trying to get a crisp shadow from an object in blender using the spot light. I've noticed I can get that with a sun light, but I specifically need to use a spot light for what I am trying to do, and it comes out blurry.

I've attached an image using the sun (left) and spot (right).

Basically is there a way for me to get the same shadow as the sun using the spot?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The setting you're looking for is the **Radius** of the point light:
[image]
[image]

A lower value will give you a sharper shadow.